# Preserving Space in an XML Document - JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML document that is similar to the example below:

```
<letter>
  <to>A</to>
  <from>B</from>
  <subject>Email Notification</subject>
  <heading>Reminder</heading> 
  <content xml:space="preserve">Thanks        Regards     </content>
</letter>
```

When I'm using JAXB to unmarshall the XML Message the space is not preserved, so the Java string variable to hold the `content` removes the spaces, inspite of having the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute.

Is there any way to retain the space in java, does the JAXB binding support this ?